# Percentage calculation problems in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, codeblocks

I am making a program that counts how many passing grades there are based on the conditions. However, when I try calculating the percentage of passing scores, that is, `if (passGrade >= 0) { printf("Percent of passing grades are %d! \n", (inputGrade/passGrade)*100);  return 0;` the program does not show the result, and instead shows up a zero, I did debug the program, and the passGrade, which is the number of total grades I entered in this line, shows up its value `printf("You have entered %d passing grades! \n", passGrade);` but when it comes to the next line, it just shows up a -1. I did look online for the problem, and nothing shows up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{

    int inputGrade, passGrade, percentGradePass;

    inputGrade = 0;
    passGrade = 0;

    /*  printf("Please type a grade (-1) to exit: ");
      scanf("%i", &inputGrade);
      printf("You typed: %i \n", inputGrade); */



    while (inputGrade != -1)
    {

        printf("Please type a grade (-1) to exit: ");
        scanf("%d", &inputGrade);
        printf("You typed: %d \n", inputGrade);

        if (inputGrade == -1)
        {
            inputGrade = -1;
        }
        else if (inputGrade >= 70 && inputGrade <= 100) {

            passGrade = passGrade + 1;

        }
        else {
            inputGrade = 0;
        }
    }


    printf("You have entered %d passing grades! \n", passGrade);
    if (passGrade >= 0) {
        printf("Percent of passing grades are %d! \n", (inputGrade/passGrade)*100);
        return 0;
   }
       

}
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `while (inputGrade != -1)` This keeps looping until `inputGrade == -1` but then in the last `printf` you use `inputGrade` again, which is guaranteed to be `-1` at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. Some issues are critical while others rather represents "strange/unnecessary" code.

Example with comments inline:

```
while (inputGrade != -1)
{

    printf("Please type a grade (-1) to exit: ");
    scanf("%d", &inputGrade);   // ALWAYS, ALWAYS... check the return value of scanf
    printf("You typed: %d \n", inputGrade);

    if (inputGrade == -1)
    {
        inputGrade = -1;  // Unnecessary! inputGrade is already -1 so no need to 
                          // assign it again
    }
    else if (inputGrade >= 70 && inputGrade <= 100) {

        passGrade = passGrade + 1;

    }
    else {
        inputGrade = 0;  // Unnecessary! inputGrade will get a new value from scanf 
                         // in the next loop
    }
}
```

So your loop could simply be:

```
while (inputGrade != -1)
{

    printf("Please type a grade (-1) to exit: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &inputGrade) != 1)
    {
        // Invalid input, terminate program
        exit(1);
    }
    
    printf("You typed: %d \n", inputGrade);

    if (inputGrade >= 70 && inputGrade <= 100) 
    {
        passGrade = passGrade + 1;
    }
}
```

Another potential issue is this:

```
(inputGrade/passGrade)*100
```

Since both variable have the type `int` the result of the division will be truncated to nearest integer, e.g. 6/10 will result in 0 instead of 0.6 and the whole expression will consequently become 0. To avoid that you can do the multiplication first (i.e. `(100 *inputGrade)/passGrade`) or use a floating point type instead of integer types.

That said, it seems that there is a basic misunderstanding in your algorithm. You say:

> I try calculating the percentage of passing scores

To calculate the percentage you want

```
100 * NumberOfPassingGrades / TotalNumberOfGrades
```

but that is **not** what you are doing. Instead of using `inputGrade` in the calculation, you need to count the number of grades and use that in the calculation.

Something like:

```
int totalGrade = 0;
while (1)
{

    printf("Please type a grade (-1) to exit: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &inputGrade) != 1)
    {
        // Invalid input, terminate program
        exit(1);
    }

    if (inputGrade != -1)
    {
        // Stop the loop
        break;
    }
    
    printf("You typed: %d \n", inputGrade);

    if (inputGrade >= 70 && inputGrade <= 100) 
    {
        passGrade = passGrade + 1;
    }
    totalGrade = totalGrade  + 1;
}

printf("You have entered %d passing grades! \n", passGrade);
printf("You have entered %d grades in total \n", totalGrade);
if (totalGrade > 0) 
{
    printf("Percent of passing grades are %d! \n", (100 * passGrade)/totalGrade);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what does 'the program does not show the result' means?

when your program reaches '(inputGrade/passGrade)*100)'

1/ you should check if 'passGrade' is 0 or not because if it is '0' there will be a run-time error.

2/ and also, since while loop is finished when 'inputGrade == -1', so you need to convert it to 'plus' before divide it

3/ lastly, since 'scanf("%d", &inputGrade);' means inputGrade = 'input' so, you dont need to write 'inputGrade = -1;' in your 'if' case